# Split a string between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split a string between these ''' characters.
My string looks like this:

```
const str = " My random text '''tag1''' '''tag2''' ";
```

and the output should look like this:  `["tag1", "tag2"]`

Comment: Try `(str.match(/'''(.*?)'''/g) || []).map((tag) => tag.replace(/'''/g, ""));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression with a capture group and [`RegEx.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to extract any substrings between three apostrophes. The pattern uses lazy matching (`.*?`) to match any sequence of characters (including none) between the apostrophes.

```
const str = " My random text '''tag1''' '''tag2''' ";
re = /'''(.*?)'''/g;
matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function getBetween(content, start, end) {
    var result = [];
    var r = content.split(start);
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        result.push(r[i].split(end)[0]);
        if (i < r.length - 1) { i++; } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = getBetween(str, "'''", "'''");
```

which results in

```
["tag1", "tag2"]
```

### Proof

```js
const str1 = " My random text '''tag1''' '''tag2''' "; 
const str2 = "String '''tag1''' this will work '''tag2'''.";
const str3 = "'''tag1''' '''tag2''' sup man '''tag3'''";

function getBetween(content, start, end) {
    var result = [];
    var r = content.split(start);
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        result.push(r[i].split(end)[0]);
        if (i < r.length - 1) { i++; }
    }
    return result;
}

var result1 = getBetween(str1, "'''", "'''");
var result2 = getBetween(str2, "'''", "'''");
var result3 = getBetween(str3, "'''", "'''");

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think a short and sweet method would be :

```
var regex = /(?<=''')\w+(?=''')/mgi;
var matches =  "My random text '''tag1''' '''tag2'''".match(regex);
```

with a result of : (2) ["tag1", "tag2"]

It matches everything between any occurence of '''.

Comment: Lookbehinds are not part of the official ECMAScript spec yet.

Comment: Also, the OP didn’t specify that tags could only be `\w+`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using template literal like below:

```
str.split(`'''`);
```

The result may look like this:

```
[" My random text ", "tag1", " ", "tag2", " "]
```

Hope this help ;)